# extjs 6 build async loaded scripts

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I'm using extjs6 to developing something, some of scripts is async loaded after I click a button to add a tab to tab panel, this scripts did not include in the build directory when I build my app via `sencha app build`. What way is right when build the application at this situation?

any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if the scripts should be dynamic i would use the Ext.loader functionalities.

If not, simply include them in your index.html.

The dynamic way could look like this:

```
Ext.define('muzkatMap.Module', {
    singleton: true,

    loadAssets: function () {
        return this.loadMapScripts();
    },

    filesLoaded: false,

    scriptPaths: [
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.1.17/leaflet-providers.js'
    ],

    loadMapScripts: function () {
        var loadingArray = [], me = this;
        return new Ext.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Ext.Array.each(me.scriptPaths, function (url) {
                loadingArray.push(me.loadMapScript(url));
            });

            Ext.Promise.all(loadingArray).then(function (success) {
                    console.log('artefacts were loaded successfully');
                    resolve('Loading was successful');
                },
                function (error) {
                    reject('Error during artefact loading...');
                });
        });
    },

    loadMapScript: function (url) {
        return new Ext.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Ext.Loader.loadScript({
                url: url,
                onLoad: function () {
                    console.log(url + ' was loaded successfully');
                    resolve();
                },
                onError: function (error) {
                    reject('Loading was not successful for: ' + url);
                }
            });
        });
    }

});
```

And you simply call in you code:

```
muzkatMap.Module.loadAssets().then(function(){
// do something with the newly available components
})
```